# Swift region monitoring - custom shapes

Tags: swift, location, maps, geofencing

I have a Google Maps API integrated in my app and I have drawn some custom shapes in the map and I'd like to trigger an event when user enters one of these shapes. I found out there is a way of monitoring if user entered a circular area using `CLCircularRegion` , but don't see anything for custom shapes. Shape in my case is basically an Array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you mean is drawing polyline

I have a sample code that might match the results you want

```
func addCustomShapeInMap( drawableLoc:[CLLocationCoordinate2D]) {

        isDrawingModeEnabled = true
        let path = GMSMutablePath()
        for loc in drawableLoc{
            path.add(loc)

        }
        let newpolygon = GMSPolygon(path: path)
        newpolygon.strokeWidth = 3
        newpolygon.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 20.0/255.0, green: 119.0/255.0, blue: 234.0/255.0, alpha: 0.75)
        newpolygon.fillColor = UIColor(red: 156.0/255.0, green: 202.0/255.0, blue: 254.0/255.0, alpha: 0.4)
        newpolygon.map = mapView
        userDrawablePolygons.append(newpolygon)

        if drawableLoc.count > 2 {
            let coordinateBounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: newpolygon.path!)
            mapView.animate(with: .fit(coordinateBounds))
        }
    }
```

hope this help. :)